# Debug assertion failed when deleting a vector of pointers

Tags: c++

I have a `vector` that holds a `pointer` to classes:

```
vector<Entity*> editorElements;
vector<Entity*> entities;
vector<DirectionalLight*> dirLights;
vector<PointLight*> pointLights;
vector<SpotLight*> spotLights;
```

This code is within my class `Scene`. The `Scene`'s ctor and destructors are like so:

```
Scene()
{
    editorElements = vector<Entity*>();
    entities = vector<Entity*>();
    dirLights = vector<DirectionalLight*>();
    pointLights = vector<PointLight*>();
    spotLights = vector<SpotLight*>();
}

~Scene()
{
    delete[] &entities;  // ERROR HERE
    delete[] &dirLights;
    delete[] &pointLights;
    delete[] &spotLights;
    delete[] &editorElements;
}
```

In the destructor I marked a line `ERROR HERE`. It doesn't matter which vector I put first, I always get the error. 
Strange is, it was working fine until lately (wasn't touching anything within the `Scene` class, or in any other classes that use an instance of `Scene`) and all of a sudden it raised an exception:

[image]

It doesn't matter if the `vector`s are empty or have elements, it gives the error all the same.

I require assistance to get this sorted out.

Comment: Where did you get the idea the you should use `delete` with vectors? You can't have seen any examples of it.

Comment: All the assignments in you constructor are unnecessary. You're just replacing one empty vector with another.

Comment: For the first - I have seen them using arrays and coming from a c#/java background, where Lists are like pumped arrays I thought it would work too. So far c++ didn't complain. Fir the second, I know, just for no apparent reason I wanted to make sure.

Comment: I would strongly advise trying to learn C++ properly rather than writing something like C# or Java and expecting it to work. Even if it compiles and _appears_ to work, you can get unpredictable Undefined Behaviour if you don't know what you're doing. Finally, if you do end up with something that happens to work, it will probably be very ugly and inefficient C++.

Comment: I know, that's why I started this whole rendering stuff in Java, using lwjgl. But that was terrible and I wasted a lot of time so I rather switched to c++.

Comment: You should take a look at the [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Despite the syntactic similarities, C++ is very different from the languages you're familiar with.

Comment: @agiro *and coming from a c#/java background* -- To add what was stated, even *if* you got your program to work using Java-like coding, the program will probably be less efficient, full of hidden errors, and will just plain look weird to any seasoned C++ programmer.  Things like using `new` all over the place when not necessary, creating "god" objects and deriving classes from it instead of using templates, etc.  There are tell-tale markers that indicates the programmer failed to actually learn C++ and are using Java or C# as a model in writing C++ code.  Don't fall into that trap.

Comment: You really can't learn `C++` using guesswork and compiler hints. You need to study it from a reliable text.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie words to live by. The second part of your comment, especially the _new all over the place_, was that in general or specifically about my code? 
I use that only for objects I want to force to heap and will live until I destroy them myself or I stop the game's execution. I use pointers/refs when I need to modify an object's properties somewhere else so I can pass them around. I don't use `new` all over the code e.g. as local variables or passing matrices, vec3-s etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [delete expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) `delete [] x` is described thus:

> Destroys an array created by a new[]-expression

So `delete[] &entities` *only* makes sense if `&entities` is an array created by a `new[]`-expression. Right?

But `entities` is a `std::vector<Entity*>`, not an `Entity[]`. You didn't create it with `new[]`, so you **must not** delete it with `delete[]`.

`std::vector` isn't syntactic sugar for an array, it's a template class, and `std::vector<Entity*> entities` isn't an array, it's an object with a constructor and destructor. That also tells us that this statement

```
entities = vector<Entity*>();
```

does nothing useful - `entities` is an object, so it was already default-constructed. You're just default constructing an anonymous temporary of the same type, and assigning it.

Finally, storing raw pointers in a vector is OK here as the vector isn't responsible for the objects' lifetimes. In most situations it's preferable to have the vector own the objects so you don't have to worry about deleting them manually, either directly with

```
vector<Entity>
```

or indirectly with

```
vector<unique_ptr<Entity>>
```

---

NB. a good guideline is: you shouldn't be using `new`, `new[]`, `delete` or `delete[]` *at all* in user code.

Use a class object to manage your storage, because the compiler will take care of calling its constructors and destructors for you.

If you need a custom class, write one that *only* manages memory, so that stays decoupled from your program logic. Otherwise just use the standard library facilities like `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` if you really need that ownership model, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Entity is like a "thing" within the game, with properties like a mesh, textures, transforms, shaders and the like. As a result I wanted to force them to heap and keep track of them in one single place - the scene, and delete the objects there when the game has finished. I'll use the smart pointer approach then.

Comment: "storing raw pointers in a vector is frequently a bad idea, because..." Not all raw pointers need to be deleted.

Comment: "storing raw pointers in a vector ... if the vector is supposed to own them." But yeah, I can probably clarify: that sentence came out as badly as Java translated into C++.

Answer (score 2):

The vectors aren't newed pointers, let alone newed arrays. So you shouldn't be deleting them. ***If*** you need to call delete on the pointers stored in the vectors, you should loop over the vectors, deleting each element. But you may be better off storing smart pointers instead (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Entity>`. That is if you need to store pointers to dynamically allocated objects at all.

Note that if you do end up deleting elements in the destructor, you will also need to take care of the [rule of three/five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: I need to access an `Entity` or `Light` from multiple places within the code but still wish to keep track of them in one single place, but let others access the same instance (so no copying). Shall I use `shared_ptr` then?

Comment: @agiro It is probably better to see if `unique_ptr<>` satisfies your requirements first. That would fork, for example, if the `Scene` instance out-lives all the other things that need to access the entities and lights.

Comment: It sure outlives, it is managed by `EngineInternal` and has only one instance created. Surface scripting can only use the one `Scene` object's functionality that was exposed (create new entity, create a light etc)

Comment: It's fine for the vector to store raw pointers so long as something else (presumably `EngineInternal`) _is_ taking care of the entity lifetimes. Ideally _that_ should be doing it using smart pointers, or by allocating them as a `vector<Entity>`, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

> all of a sudden it raised an exception

It is because of trying to delete something you shouldn't be deleting. [The `delete[]` syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) is for deletion of a dynamically allocated *array*. But you provide it with a pointer to a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instance. So the compiler takes this address for the deletion as if it was an array, which includes finding out its size and then delete the entire segment. But there's no such appropriate figure, as this is not an array, so in run-time you end up trying to delete something in a place you don't have permission to access and thus you get the assertion failure, as this is an access violation, a.k.a. segfault.

Also, `vector` is a class that manages its own memory. If you wanted to release entities held inside this container -- that is, the individual elements themselves, allocated dynamically -- then you should loop over them and delete each one. Conveniently, for example, using [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and a [*range-based for loop*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) like this:

```
for (auto ptr : entities)
    delete ptr;
```

**But, in most scenarios you better save yourself this memory management overhead and opt for [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)** instead of the raw pointers:

```
#include <memory>
...
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entity>> entities;
```

This way you don't have to worry about freeing any memory as it will be released by the `std:: unique_ptr` once it's being destructed, as part of the `vector`'s destruction.

Further, this is unnecessary and probably not what you intended to do:

```
entities = vector<Entity*>();
```

as the `vector` object itself is already defined (so it is existing) before this line, and all it does is create an identical new one and assign it to `entities`.